# Show that the line $KD$ bisects $\angle{EKF}$

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

> Let $P$ be an interior point of an acute-angled triangle $ABC$. The line $BP$ meets the line $AC$ at $E$, and
>   the line $CP$ meets the line $AB$ at $F$. The lines $AP$ and $EF$ intersect each other at $D$. Let $K$ be the foot of
>   the perpendicular from the point $D$ to the line $BC$. Show that the line $KD$ bisects the angle $\angle{EKF}$.

**Picture**

[image]

**Attempt**

Extend $EF$ to intersect line $BC$ at $G$. Note that the pencil formed by the complete quadrangle $BCEF$ of the four lines based at each intersection of opposite sides is harmonic. Thus the cross-ratio  $(G,D,F,E) = -1$. This with the fact that $\angle{DKG} = 90^{\circ}$ should prove that $KD$ is a bisector, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$\pi_1$ is the circle that circum-scribes KEF. It cuts KD produced at H and BC at S. By converse of Thales, HS is a diameter of that circle. If US is a tangent to $\pi_1$, then, $\angle TSU = 90^0$.

Let HS cuts EF at T.

Claim:- $\pi_2$, the red dotted circle, that circum-scribes SKD also passes through T.

Proof:-

(1) SD is a diameter of $\pi_2$ for the same reason.

(2) Let $\pi_2$ cuts US at V such that $\angle TSV = \angle TSU = 90^0$. Note that V and S are points on the circumference of $\pi_2$.

The above implies T is also on $\pi_2$ and therefore, $HS \bot FE $ at $T$.

In fact, $HS$ is the perpendicular bisector of $FE$ because $EF$ is a chord perpendicular to the diameter $HS$.

Then, $\alpha = \alpha_1 = \beta_1 = \beta$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Following your partial attempt, the (Apollonius) circle with diameter $GD$ passes through $K$ because of the right-angle, and then you can angle-chase using circle properties to finish.

Comment: That's nice but can you tell me what point you are talking with respect to about the Apollonius circle? Anyway here is another method or you can use the Ratio Lemma: if you let the angles that the lines make be $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ in that order, then the condition of being harmonic because $$\sin \alpha\sin \gamma = \sin \beta \sin (\alpha+\beta+\gamma)$$If we have $\alpha=\beta$ then $$\sin \gamma = \sin (2\alpha+\gamma)\implies \gamma = \pi-2\alpha-\gamma\implies \gamma+\alpha = \dfrac{\pi}{2}\implies \gamma +\beta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$as desired; the converse is proved similarly.

Comment: @user19405892: With respect to $E,F$ of course. Every harmonic division has such an Apollonius circle (and another for $G,D$ with diameter $EF$). Then by right-angle $K$ must lie on the Apollonius circle, and then basic circle properties and similar triangles will finish. The problem is that these properties are all widely known and I don't know what order you were taught them.