# Triangle and the altitude

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, projective-geometry

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle, altitude from $A$ intersects $BC$ at $D.$ $P$ be an arbitrary point on $AD.  $ $BP$ and $CP$ intersects $AC$ and $AB$ at $X$ and $Y$ respectively.  Prove that $\angle ADX=\angle ADY.$

I almost tried everything to solve this. But it is too hard for me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a contest problem. Do you know its source?

Comment: @PrashantGokhale I don't know if it is. I have got the problem from a book called "Adventures in Problem Solving-S.Shirali".

Comment: Maybe $P$ is the incentre of triangle $DXY$? I am not sure though.

Comment: @PrashantGokhale Yeah you are right ,   that is same as $P$  be the orthocentre of $ABC$

Comment: Yes, were you able to prove it? why don't you write that as a answer yourself?

Comment: This might be considered a duplicate [of this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461459), which is a special case of [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651105) linked therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set coordinate system as $A(0,1)$, $B(b,0)$ and $C(0,c)$. Then $D(0,0)$ and $P(0,p)$ for some $p$.

Then $X({(p-1)bc\over pc-b},{p(b-c)\over pc-b})$ and so the slope from $D$ through $X$ is $k = {p(c-b)\over (p-1)bc} $.

Also $Y({(p-1)bc\over pb-c},{p(c-b)\over pb-c})$ and so the slope from $D$ through $Y$ is $k' = {p(b-c)\over (p-1)bc} = -k$.

So $\angle ADX = \angle ADY$.