# Triangles ( Menelaus and Ceva's theorem )

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

$AD$ , $BE$ , $CF$ are concurrent lines drawn from vertices of triangle $ABC$ to points $D$ , $E$ , $F$ on the opposite sides. If $AD$ is the altitude of triangle $ABC$ , prove that $AD$ bisects $\angle FDE$.

[image]

Comment: Take a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378817/triangle-and-the-altitude/2378943#2378943

Comment: I want the solution without the use of coordinate geometry.

Comment: Do you know projective geometry?

Comment: Only know bit about the 3 theorems.

Comment: oh I just realized this is a duplicate of not only what [ChristianF linked to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378817), but also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461459).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Lemma*. Let $l$ be a line parallel to $BC$ and passing through $A$. Let $P$ and $Q$ be the points of intersection of $l$ with $DE$ and $DF$ correspondingly. Then $PA=AQ$.

[image]

Proof of the lemma. Triangles FAQ and FBD are similar, so $AQ=BD\frac{AF}{FB}$. Triangles EPA and EDC are similar, so $AP = CD \frac{AE}{EC}$. These two expressions are equal by Ceva's theorem.

Solution of your problem: If $AD \perp BC$, then $AD \perp PQ$ and triangle DPQ is isosceles, so $\angle QDA = \angle ADP$