# Show that the altitude bisects the corresponding angle

Tags: geometry, area

$AD, BE$ and $CF$ are concurrent lines drawn from the vertices of $\Delta ABC$ to points $D,E,F$ (respectively) on the opposite sides. If $AD$ is the altitute, show that $AD$ bisects $\angle FDE$

I am aware of proceeding with the problem but somehow I'm not getting the final answer. I'm sure that it is based upon the usage of [Menelaus' Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27_theorem) and area chasing. The fact that the altitude is given, the usage of area chasing becomes more prominent. It may also require [Ceva's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem)

I can provide my work but since most of it is just rough work and I'm not on the right path, I'm not providing it.

Comment: @NickPavlov It's okay. Not an issue. :)

Comment: I managed to solve it with brute force - set up a coordinate system centered at D, with axes along BC and DA, then use equations of lines to find coordinates of E and F and from there slopes of DE and DF - are you interested in this approach?

Comment: @NickPavlov Did you use Barycentric coordinates?

Comment: no, just plain Cartesians, but barycentric will probably work as well

Comment: also, this seems like a very similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651105/show-that-the-line-kd-bisects-angleekf?rq=1 (in fact yours is a special case of it - so the solutions there apply equally well here)

Comment: @NickPavlov The problem in the link has previously come in an Olympiad (year 2003). I have seen that.

Answer (score 0):

[image: circle of Apollonius]Given triangle $ABC$, with $BE$, $CF$ crossing altitude $AD$ concurrently at $G$, join $DF$, $DE$. Draw $EF$, crossing $AD$ at $H$, and let $EF$ and $CB$ extended meet at $K$.

Since $K$ is the harmonic conjugate of $D$ with respect to $B,C$, then $K$ is fixed for all $G$ on $AD$ and$$\frac{KB}{KC}=\frac{BD}{DC}$$

But since $DH$, $FM$, $EL$ in triangle $DFE$ are also concurrent at $G$ (and granting that $ML$ extended passes through $K$), then $K$ is also the harmonic conjugate of $H$ with respect to $F$, $E$. And since $HD$ is perpendicular to $KD$, then $D$ lies on the circumference of a circle of Apollonius with diameter $KH$, "foci" $F$, $E$, and $$\frac{KF}{KE}=\frac{FH}{HE}=\frac{DF}{DE}$$

Therefore, by the converse of the angle bisector theorem (Euclid $VI,3$), $DH$ bisects $\angle FDE$ in triangle $DFE$.